# How to get user's facebook pages and apps list after authentication?

Tags: facebook

After a user install my application to his/her facebook page,I want to get his/her facebook pages and apps list.

I have read these documents:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/application/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/developer/

What is the **best way** to do?

Another question:

**How to check if a user is my app's user?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't really looked at the documentation, but they are fairly clear questions, so...

1. After getting the `user_likes` permission you can query `/me/likes` to get a list of pages the user likes. A list of apps is not currently possible in the same way.
2. A call to `/me/permissions` or `/me/?fields=installed` will show if the current app is installed by the current user
3. A call to `/me/accounts` with the 'manage_pages' permission will show which pages and apps a user admins, but not which pages and apps they use.

Comment: Thank you for adding one more answer.

I have tried /me/accounts to get pages and apps list. Used /me/permissions and /me/?fields=installed to confirm whether current app is installed by the current user. The return value was 1.However,the app hasn't been installed to the pages or apps of current user.

How to check it?

Comment: There's no way to check true/false in the API, but each time an app is loaded from a page tab you will receive a callback which includes the page ID so you can track it that way, see this answer here for more info: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7232897/create-facebook-tab-for-only-my-company-page/7233287#7233287

Answer (score 2):

You can use FQL to query this information.

```
select uid, name, is_app_user from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()) and is_app_user=1
```

Answer (score 1):

The user needs to allow (and be user of) your app in order to be able to authenticate though oauth.

You can list the user's pages and apps by accessing:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts
```

or

```
https://graph.facebook.com/%user_id%/accounts
```

But you must also provide the user oauth token.